# message class 'mongoclient' not found codeigniter

Tags: php, codeigniter

I am trying to setup mongo db in codeigniter after doing setup when I run my controller getting this error. I have tried similler error on stackoverflow but no luck. here is the error:

```
Fatal error: Class 'MongoClient' not found in /var/www/html/grant/application/libraries/Mongo_db.php on line 216
A PHP Error was encountered

Severity: Error

Message: Class 'MongoClient' not found

Filename: libraries/Mongo_db.php

Line Number: 216

Backtrace:
```

Comment: some files for mongo are missing, see this, https://github.com/vesparny/cimongo-codeigniter-mongodb-library

Comment: vhave you tried to activate mongodb $this->load->library('mongo_db', array('activate'=>'newdb'),'mongo_db2');

Answer (score 0):

Your Mongo_db class is expecting that the MongoClient class has already been loaded and Mongo_db is trying to instantiate it. Your question didn't include the link to the Mongo library you are using so I'm unable to debug further, however here are the basic steps.

Before loading your Mongo_db library try loading Mongo_client

```
$this->load->library('mongo_client');
```

If your libraries rely on composer autoloader make sure that you have included the autoloader class somewhere in your bootstrap or configuration

```
include 'vendor/autoload.php'
```

If your libraries rely on composer, you may also want to check your autoload make sure you are including your libraries directory in the class map:

```
{
    "autoload": {
        "classmap": ["application/libraries"]
    }
}
```

If you updated your autoload configuration in your composer.json file make sure to run this command

```
composer dump-autoload
```